# What does this image mean exactly?

Tags: numerical-methods

[image]

This is an image of the cover of my numerical analysis book. I can see there is a curve and a tangent line to the curve at a point, of course slope of this line is equal to derivative of function of the curve at that point. but we can see also a purple right triangle in the image and its hypotenuse slope seems approximately equal to slope of tangent line. but I am very curious to know how this purple triangle formed and why its these slope are equal? does this image state a concept about numerical methods?

Comment: The triangle does not look quite like a right triangle to me — the angle in the bottom right seems a little acute more than just perspective would account for. Most likely it is just a graphic design accent, though I can't say for sure.

Comment: It looks like Newton's method